# Visual Studio 2008 and tfs-git / visual studio online

Tags: git, visual-studio-2008, tfs, azure-devops

Anyone using VS2008 connect to tfs-git (visual studio online) ?
I've tried to create git repository on VSO but cannot connect via VS2008, got this error

"TF401191: A version control folder for team project '' could not be created because another source control system is enabled for that team project."

sorry I cannot post an error image.

Answer (score 0):

We did not add git support to VS 2008. That is built into VS 2013, and it is available as an add-in for VS 2012 at http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/abafc7d6-dcaa-40f4-8a5e-d6724bdb980c.